# Which VirtualBox repository should I use for Kubuntu 20.10?

Tags: apt, package-management, virtualbox, repository, 20.10

I have Kubuntu 20.10

The [Ubunutu 20.10 codename](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history) is "Groovy Gorilla".

It is based on Debian 11 "bullseye":

```
$ cat /etc/debian_version 
bullseye/sid
```

I want to set-up a [VirtualBox apt repository](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) so to don't have to download new versions manually. In the VirtualBox documentation there is written:

> Add the following line to your /etc/apt/sources.list. According to
> your distribution, replace '' with 'eoan', 'bionic', 'xenial',
> 'buster', 'stretch', or 'jessie' (older versions of VirtualBox
> supported different distributions):
>
> deb [arch=amd64] https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian
>  contrib

If I open [the "dists" folder](https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/dists/) there is no "groovy" and no "bullseye".

My choices seems to be either "focal" (Ubuntu 20.04) or "buster" (Debian 10).

Which one should I use, if I can use anything of those at all?

Comment: You may use 'focal' that's the latest LTS version.

Comment: Adding an upstream repository is optional, and recommended only for folks who have a specific reason for using the vanilla upstream version. Virtualbox in the Ubuntu repositories, *which you already have*, works very well for most users.

Comment: @user535733 This is a new topic that maybe I will discuss in another question. I have found in the Calibre website "Please do not use your distribution provided calibre package, as those are often buggy/outdated. Instead use the Binary install described below.". I found it to be true for every package, not only for Calibre. The versions in Canonical repositories are old and bugged. This is true also for VirtualBox. In the repository 6.1.14 and bugged (problems in displaying icons), official version 6.1.16 and works ok (no problems with the icons)

Comment: @user535733 For Calibre the situation is even more critical: in Canonical repositories, v. 4.99.12. Current version: 5.7.2